# Call MySQL Stored Procedure on PHP

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

can anyone help me on how to call stored proc in php? I have a below function that call mysql stored proc but it commits an error.

```
public function getProductionItems($selectedProjectID,$selectedTaskID,$processingType,$isFirstTask)
    {
        $prodItemList = array();

        $strQry = "CALL getProductionItem(".$selectedProjectID.",".$selectedTaskID.",".$processingType.",".$isFirstTask.")";
        $mysqli = new mysqli();
        $mysqli = $this->getPvtConnection();
        $stmt = $mysqli->query($strQry);

        while($data = $stmt->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $prodItem = new productionItemModel();
            $prodItem->setTaskQueueID($data['taskQueueID']);
            $prodItem->setProdItemName($data['prodItemName']);
            array_push($prodItemList,$prodItem);
        }
        mysqli_free_result($stmt);
        $mysqli->close();

        return $prodItemList;
    }
```

Error encountered is : Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in C:\AppServ\www\ptsproject\dao\projecttask\projtaskdao.php on line 1298

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing `'`:

```
 $strQry = "CALL getProductionItem('$selectedProjectID','$selectedTaskID','$processingType','$isFirstTask')";
```

Comment: yeah, i missed ' on $processingType since it's a varchar.. thanks